# System.Management.ManagementException "Unsupported display" in my virtual machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception

When running my program in my virtual machine for some kind of reason it fails to fetch the display information:

```
var success = true;

List<Display> displays = new List<Display>();

// Query WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams to retrieve display parameters
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams"))
using (var results = searcher.Get())
```

Here at the result variable if the program is not  run in a virtual machine I obtain the result string, otherwise in my vmware machine I obtain the following exception (I'm currently running the program on Windows 10):

> Unhandled exception. System.Management.ManagementException: Not supported
>
> at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
> at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()

Comment: What kind of VM are you running on?  Does it have a 'display' ?

Comment: Yes it's a Vmware Windows 10 X64 bit machine,  it's booted in BIOS mode, virtual space type is of SCSI type, ram 8 gb, the monitor is generic NON plug and play device, and the driver is the vmware one, also i have installed vmware tools already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by rewriting the System.Management.dll with dnSpy and then pushing the changes in the global caches with ngen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).